# Acronis True Image Boot Error

Tags: acronis-trueimage

I created a new image using Acronis True Image 2010 Home (boot cd) just yesterday. Today when I used the boot media again to create a new image I face an error. It initially boots correctly but then it goes into a black screen before it reaches the interface and the Caps-Lock and Scroll-Lock key blink together and then nothing happens.

Has anyone faced such an error before? What is the problem as my computer boots into Windows correctly.

**Additional input:** It boots to the interface if I use the safe version, is it okay to use the safe version?

Comment: Why don't you ask Acronis Support?

Comment: @harrymc yep i'm on that, just thought that I would give this place a go first. Just in case someone knew how to solve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have issues with the Acronis recovery software booting from a USB key.

I found that it was hanging at a certain point. I turned off, and rebooted the laptop with the external Hard Drive disconnected, and only connected it when the Acronis software wanted to find the image to restore from.

I was using a 2TB hard drive ... Can't remember whether it was the Seagate Expansion drive or my Western Digital one.  Incidentally I have to say that the Seagate Expansion drives seem to have an inherent design flaw - google "Seagate Expansion hard drive click" and check their forums ... so maybe that was a contributing factor.

I restored recently by booting from USB, and then connecting the external drive later on.

Comment: I have a Western Digital HardDisk

Answer (score 2):

According to your description it looks like Acronis Loader (on which the CD is based) cannot properly access the hardware. The best workaround here is to [download the updated media built on an alternative loader](http://kb.acronis.com/content/4828).

Since the media is in ISO format, you need to [burn it onto a CD](http://kb.acronis.com/content/1810) (or load to USB). After that boot the machine with the new CD/USB and see whether the issue persists.